# Selenium PHPUnit - Not able to find a text on page

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

There is a problem regarding selenium PHPUnit.

```
PHPUnit version: 3.7.21
OS: Windows7
Selenium Server: selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2
```

I am getting a very weird situation, that I have a text present on the page, and using `assertTextPresent()` function on that page only. But it continuously fail.

Earlier I thought, may be it because of page not loaded properly. So I just use `pause()` for page to load. And now I am able to see the text on page.

I also captured the screenshot, In that screenshot I am also able to see that pattern.

But there is something wrong, that this function is not able to find text in the page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a more specific example of what steps you're performing and what parameters you're using? Anyway, you could wait for an element to be present on the page like this:

```
for ($second = 0; ; $second++) {
    if ($second >= 30) $this->fail("Element not found");
    try {
        if ($value == $this->getText("$locator")) break;
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
    sleep(1);
}
```

where $value is the text you're looking for and $locator is the path where you expect to find the text. OR (if you don't care about where the text needs to be):

```
for ($second = 0; ; $second++) {
    if ($second >= 30) $this->fail("\n Text not found");
    try {
        if ($this->isTextPresent("$value")) break;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as a workaround

```
$txt = $this->byXPath("insert-xpath-of-text-here")->text();
$this->assertTrue($txt,"text-to-be-found","some-random-error-message-here");
```

or

```
$this->assertTrue($this->byXPath("insert-xpath-of-text-here")->text(),"text-to-be-found","some-random-error-message-here");
```

I figured that indicating the locator of the text to be found might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

$this->waitForPageLoad(1000);
You are using this method
assertElementExistsWithText_W();